# Cassnadra cqlsh login error

Tags: cassandra, cqlsh

I have two nodes Cassandra(3.10) cluster. I am trying to migrate Mysql data to Cassandra. Everything was working fine but now after transferring 1.5 TB of data, I tried to login on cluster -

```
cqlsh 192.168.22.231
```

I got the following error :

```
Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'192.168.22.229': ReadFailure('Error from server: code=1300 [Replica(s) failed to execute read] message="Operation failed - received 0 responses and 1 failures" info={\'failures\': 1, \'received_responses\': 0, \'required_responses\': 1, \'consistency\': \'ONE\'}',)})
```

Migration is still going on and 
Nodetool status is working fine :

```
nodetool status
Datacenter: dc1
===============
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address         Load       Tokens       Owns (effective)  Host ID                               Rack
UN  192.168.22.229  1.49 TiB   256          100.0%            335fc3a2-c21f-44ad-a937-487ba457c2fa  rack1
UN  192.168.22.231  1.63 TiB   256          100.0%            a5eaf96c-eaf9-4e2e-bd6b-6186ce944cd0  rack1
```

I could not find much in system.log file-

```
WARN  [CompactionExecutor:1235] 2017-07-24 09:18:36,909 BigTableWriter.java:211 - Writing large partition system/size_estimates:compare_prices (148.685MiB) to sstable /var/lib/cassandra/data/system/size_estimates-618f817b005f3678b8a453f3930b8e86/mc-86529-big-Data.db
WARN  [CompactionExecutor:1237] 2017-07-24 09:18:41,057 BigTableWriter.java:211 - Writing large partition system/size_estimates:compare_prices (304.941MiB) to sstable /var/lib/cassandra/data/system/size_estimates-618f817b005f3678b8a453f3930b8e86/mc-86524-big-Data.db
INFO  [Service Thread] 2017-07-24 09:19:13,717 GCInspector.java:284 - ConcurrentMarkSweep GC in 288ms.  CMS Old Gen: 6914586928 -> 7048104592; Par Eden Space: 912792 -> 279263336; Par Survivor Space: 39217480 -> 22677312
WARN  [CompactionExecutor:1235] 2017-07-24 09:19:21,054 BigTableWriter.java:211 - Writing large partition system/size_estimates:compare_prices (304.983MiB) to sstable /var/lib/cassandra/data/system/size_estimates-618f817b005f3678b8a453f3930b8e86/mc-86532-big-Data.db
INFO  [GossipTasks:1] 2017-07-24 09:19:39,143 Gossiper.java:1035 - InetAddress /192.168.22.229 is now DOWN
INFO  [HANDSHAKE-/192.168.22.229] 2017-07-24 09:19:40,144 OutboundTcpConnection.java:510 - Handshaking version with /192.168.22.229
INFO  [RequestResponseStage-1] 2017-07-24 09:19:40,707 Gossiper.java:1020 - InetAddress /192.168.22.229 is now UP
INFO  [RequestResponseStage-2] 2017-07-24 09:19:40,707 Gossiper.java:1020 - InetAddress /192.168.22.229 is now UP
INFO  [RequestResponseStage-3] 2017-07-24 09:19:40,708 Gossiper.java:1020 - InetAddress /192.168.22.229 is now UP
INFO  [HANDSHAKE-/192.168.22.229] 2017-07-24 09:19:40,713 OutboundTcpConnection.java:510 - Handshaking version with /192.168.22.229
INFO  [Service Thread] 2017-07-24 09:19:56,535 GCInspector.java:284 - ConcurrentMarkSweep GC in 368ms.  CMS Old Gen: 6912138512 -> 7064530672; Code Cache: 53907904 -> 53912512; Par Eden Space: 346891848 -> 410552160; Par Survivor Space: 22163952 -> 56682672
INFO  [Service Thread] 2017-07-24 09:20:11,484 GCInspector.java:284 - ConcurrentMarkSweep GC in 290ms.  CMS Old Gen: 7101380632 -> 7024862456; Par Eden Space: 1766944 -> 325018648; Par Survivor Space: 74151808 -> 45360640
INFO  [Service Thread] 2017-07-24 09:20:27,528 GCInspector.java:284 - ConcurrentMarkSweep GC in 286ms.  CMS Old Gen: 7063164264 -> 6923704424; Par Eden Space: 4215840 -> 423685008; Par Survivor Space: 51589440 -> 42734824
```

Any idea to rectify this problem will be appreciable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is running cqlsh locally works?

Make sure that you have port 9042 open in your firewall.

Also, you can try running:

**cqlsh --connect-timeout=60 --request-timeout=60**